# How to delete a resource based on the property of JSONB Array in Sequelize(postgres)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a model like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const MatterResource = sequelize.define('MatterResource', {
    ...
    attached_resources: {
        type:DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB)<<<<,
        allownull: true,
        defaultValue: [] 
    }
  }, {});
```

Now I am trying to delete where matterId=? and public_id=? in JSONB array but it's not working, any ideas on what I should do right?

This is what I am currently doing

```
try {
            const resource = await model.MatterResource.destroy({
             where: {
                matterId,
                attached_resources:{
                    [sequelize.Op.contains]: [ { public_id : req.params.public_id } ]<<<<< issue
            }
        }
              })
              console.log('RESOURCE', resource);
              return res.status(204).json({
                  status: 204,
                  resource,
                  message: 'Resource deleted'
              });

        } catch(error){
            return res.status(500).json({
                err: error.message
            })
    }
```

This is the generated SQL statement in postgres:

`Executing (default): DELETE FROM "MatterResources" WHERE "matterId" = 1 AND "attached_resources" @> ARRAY['{"public_id":"cl9lvbwv0ern0evjhwj7"}']::JSONB[]`

**P.S: This is how the get All query looks like and I want to delete a single object in attached_resources array by public_id**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "userId": 2,
            "matterId": 1,
            "attached_resources": [
                {
                    "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/raw/upload/v1589386451/cl9lvbwv0ern0evjhwj7",
                    "etag": "c6df9fb62e7bbd43863974e4c3b04dd8",
                    "tags": [],
                    "type": "upload",
                    "bytes": 18522,
                    "version": 1589386451,
                    "asset_id": "55f231d46d0af9e10e3f097407ef26b5",
                    "public_id": "cl9lvbwv0ern0evjhwj7",**<<<< delete this resource object>>>**
                    "signature": "b588dd30ab296f94e8c0dc0d779a5bf419d96d1c",
                    "created_at": "2020-05-13T16:14:11Z",
                    "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/raw/upload/v1589386451/cl9lvbwv0ern0evjhwj7",
                    "version_id": "e588644a9bc332ca9e93755105c1cb66",
                    "placeholder": false,
                    "resource_type": "raw",
                    "original_filename": "tmp-5-1589386448929"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/raw/upload/v1589386450/xuzdvmecupyxqdgl29db",
                    "etag": "d6748148bac91abcee41015b4464504b",
                    "tags": [],
                    "type": "upload",
                    "bytes": 7168,
                    "version": 1589386450,
                    "asset_id": "0ec2c2c7cc3e4d4ed39092c45729ac5b",
                    "public_id": "xuzdvmecupyxqdgl29db",
                    "signature": "e743b6b27eff484f85626dbecdffe500ed546908",
                    "created_at": "2020-05-13T16:14:10Z",
                    "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/raw/upload/v1589386450/xuzdvmecupyxqdgl29db",
                    "version_id": "9adc0957a8aa4d02b9e704338662473e",
                    "placeholder": false,
                    "resource_type": "raw",
                    "original_filename": "tmp-6-1589386448930"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/image/upload/v1589386451/tlqpw1ucieucogcw2tqu.png",
                    "etag": "679ebf6c248f84e24c626121a709970f",
                    "tags": [],
                    "type": "upload",
                    "bytes": 115093,
                    "width": 1280,
                    "format": "png",
                    "height": 800,
                    "version": 1589386451,
                    "asset_id": "805d3f8add93e7cb29feeeb148492848",
                    "public_id": "tlqpw1ucieucogcw2tqu",
                    "signature": "4d06d0768df3f9123dca8b20920e15091a522e3b",
                    "created_at": "2020-05-13T16:14:11Z",
                    "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/image/upload/v1589386451/tlqpw1ucieucogcw2tqu.png",
                    "version_id": "f4fbcee1c41238e64ce1794a366da8a3",
                    "placeholder": false,
                    "resource_type": "image",
                    "original_filename": "tmp-7-1589386448930"
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/image/upload/v1589386452/pxv7bfxq0xzsmbwhimjd.pdf",
                    "etag": "2d2a56b6a319985c73b5d4b39470983d",
                    "tags": [],
                    "type": "upload",
                    "bytes": 786377,
                    "pages": 4,
                    "width": 612,
                    "format": "pdf",
                    "height": 792,
                    "version": 1589386452,
                    "asset_id": "aaa4e446282c373d555bc0fc20c64868",
                    "public_id": "pxv7bfxq0xzsmbwhimjd",
                    "signature": "d174ba4f79faefe0800ac908bac2e8d1812a2a7e",
                    "created_at": "2020-05-13T16:14:12Z",
                    "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/nuwa/image/upload/v1589386452/pxv7bfxq0xzsmbwhimjd.pdf",
                    "version_id": "009fdf1eb136dafa01308af023fb8e1c",
                    "placeholder": false,
                    "resource_type": "image",
                    "original_filename": "tmp-8-1589386448935"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2020-05-13T16:14:12.750Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-13T16:14:12.750Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { DataTypes, Model, Op } from 'sequelize';

class MatterResource extends Model {}
MatterResource.init(
  {
    attached_resources: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: [],
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'matter_resource' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await MatterResource.bulkCreate([
      { attached_resources: [{ public_id: 1 }] },
      { attached_resources: [{ public_id: 2 }] },
      { attached_resources: [{ public_id: 3 }] },
    ]);
    // test
    const resource = await MatterResource.destroy({
      where: {
        attached_resources: {
          [Op.contains]: [{ public_id: 1 }],
        },
      },
    });
    console.log(resource);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

Check the database:

```
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from matter_resource;
 id |   attached_resources
----+------------------------
  2 | {"{\"public_id\": 2}"}
  3 | {"{\"public_id\": 3}"}
(2 rows)
```

The logs of executing the script:

```js
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "matter_resource" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "matter_resource" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "matter_resource" ("id"   SERIAL , "attached_resources" JSONB[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::JSONB[], PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'matter_resource' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "matter_resource" ("id","attached_resources") VALUES (DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"public_id":1}']::JSONB[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"public_id":2}']::JSONB[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"public_id":3}']::JSONB[]) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): DELETE FROM "matter_resource" WHERE "attached_resources" @> ARRAY['{"public_id":1}']::JSONB[]
1
```

Comment: Kindly check the update I made. The current solution you suggested did not work

Comment: @camelCase It a simple example and works fine. Did you get any error?

Comment: No error but when I do a getAll, it still returns the object with that public_id. I have updated the question with the get All response.